# How do I make my square not flip over in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning to code and make games in unity, so I am very much a beginner. I made a little square jumping game in 2D that can jump, and move Left and Right. But for some reason the physics make it so that my square can flip over and it wont jump after it does. I have a GameObject that is named feetPos so that my square can jump, but as soon as the square flips over it wont jump again. is there any way to fix this? Or make my square not flip over?

(I don't know how to put link of the code)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this would help your specific issue. But to stop rotation of  your square entirely once it jumps you could:

- go to the Rigidbody2D Component for your square,
- and then navigate to Constraints:

[image]

then selecting the 'Freeze Rotation' option for the z-axis of your square

you can find out more about RigidBody2D rotation on the [unity manual docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html) for the different types of body types your Rigidbody2d component may use:

Comment: That really helped, thank you so much!

Comment: @MaikoArtist if an answer solves your question please accept the answer via the `✓` button. This a) rewards the author of the answer with some reputation, b) shows others that this question already has a solution, c) helps future users with the same or similar questions to easier find answers with a valid solution and therefore d) also rewards yourself ;)